# How to know if time complexity is O(n+m) or O(n*m)

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, asymptotics, big-o-notation

I'm having difficulty understanding when can we know if the time complexity of an algorithm is n+m or n*m

Is the time complexity of the following algo **O(n+m) or O(n*m)**

Can you please point me to a resource that can give some sample examples of code patterns for different variations of time complexity?

For example:

```
for(String str : strs) {
   char[] charArray = str.toCharArray();
   Array.sort(charArray); //ignoring the TC of this one, which would be nLogn in java
   System.out.println("sorted: "+ new String(charArray));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Read [The Algorithm Design Manual](http://mimoza.marmara.edu.tr/%7Emsakalli/cse706_12/SkienaTheAlgorithmDesignManual.pdf).

For this specific question, refer **Section 2.5**.

Basically you need to count the number of atomic operations your algorithm is performing.

Comment: Please include the gist of your answer *in* your post.